# Updating A Profile Model Object in Django

Tags: python, django, object, models

I've searched and searched to try to figure out my issue or what I need to do here. I'm new to Django and havn't quite gotten the hang of allowing a user to change a model Object of a database through a form.

What my code is doing is creating a default 'Profile' database whenever the user signs up with the following code:

Models.py:

```
    class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    state = models.CharField(max_length= 20, choices=STATE_CHOICES,default='N/A',)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    Primary_Campaign_Interest = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=Interest_choices, null='000')
    Secondary_Campaign_Interest = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=Interest_choices, null='000')

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

This generates an empty table in my database that I would like the user to then be able to edit through a form. However, I would only like for the user to be able to edit the state and city fields along with some of the user fields, not the username.

forms.py

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = ('state','city')
```

views.py

```
@login_required
@transaction.atomic
def update_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = SignUpForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, _('Your profile was successfully updated!'))
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            return render(request, 'Users/profile.html')
    else:
        user_form = SignUpForm(instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', {
        'user_form': user_form,
        'profile_form': profile_form
    })
```

accounts/profile.html

```
    <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  <h3>First name:</h3>
  {{ user_form.first_name }}<br>
  <h3>Last name:</h3>
  {{ user_form.last_name }}<br>
  <h3>Email Address:</h3>
  {{ user_form.email }}<br>
  <h3>State:</h3>
  {{ profile_form.state }}<br>
  <h3>City:</h3>
  {{ profile_form.city}}<br>
  <h3>Primary Campaign Interest:</h3>
  {{ profile_form.Primary_Campaign_Interest}}<br>
  <h3>Secondary Campaign Interest:</h3>
  {{profile_form.Secondary_Campaign_Interest}}<br>
  <button type="submit">Save changes</button>
</form>
```

I believe my issue is that whenever a user submits these forms, the forms are not valid and return the page Users/Profile.html. Any suggestion on making the forms valid? Or a better way to edit objects already in a database?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Also I think the `return render` statement should be inside the else statement at the end, and you probably would want to pass `user_form` and `profile_form` as context or args into that just to clean it up a bit

Answer (score 0):

I personally think you should seperate your task into two tasks. First of all, you create a new user (your signup form), save it to database (task 1). If it is saved auccessfully, then you shoumd be able to use a update view to query that user from your database, then update it and save it (task 2).

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out a bit ago. I just created a new form, passed it into the view, and then set the initial values to the values that were currently in the model object.
Also important to note the use of the user instance.

```
@login_required
def signuptwo(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
        profile = form.save(commit=False)
        profile.user = request.user
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        form = EditProfileForm(initial={'state':user_profile.state,'city':user_profile.city,'birth_date':user_profile.birth_date,'Primary_Campaign_Interest':user_profile.Primary_Campaign_Interest,'Secondary_Campaign_Interest':user_profile.Secondary_Campaign_Interest})
        return render(request, 'Accounts/Editprofile.html', {'form':form})
```

Thanks for the help!